# Filtering in array list Filterable Not cancelling the previous filter

Tags: android, android-listview, filter

I have seen the filter method documentation which shows that calling the filter cancels all previous non-executed filtering requests and posts a new filtering request that will be executed later.

But the actual callback which i received is some how different.In my implementation it is not cancelling the previous filter request and calls the `publishResults()` method for the previous search criteria after the recent search criteria .The logs are as follows:

```
  10-03 17:49:41.781: E/TAG(2150): onTextChanged first Criteria  
  10-03 17:49:41.781: E/TAG(2150): performFiltering first Criteria  
  10-03 17:49:41.961: E/TAG(2150): onTextChanged second Criteria   
  10-03 17:49:41.961: E/TAG(2150): performFiltering second Criteria  
  10-03 17:49:42.195: E/TAG(2150): publishResults second Criteria   
  10-03 17:49:42.219: E/TAG(2150): publishResults first Criteria
```

Comment: you need to keep track of the initial list and perform the second filtering on the it.

Comment: @njzk2  Can you please elaborate a little more.

Comment: are you using the same instance of a Filter?

Comment: I have implemented this in this way:     
@Override  
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int  arg3)
{
   Log.e("TAG", "onTextChanged" +arg0);
   adapter.getFilter().filter(arg0);
}

Comment: again: is adapter.getFilter() the same object when you are using it?

Comment: @pskink I am returning a new object from the getFilter() Method

Comment: log adapter.getFilter()

Comment: @pskink Thanks!  My problem is solved by using a single instance of adapter.getFilter().

Comment: Sorry, how did you resolved? I guess I have the same problem, cause when I type fast on an autocompleteTextView seems like the filter() method is called in a LIFO mode and I see all the previous results before the last one updated List of suggestions. This way the autocompleteTextView is really really slow... What did you did? Thanks

Comment: You have to use only single instance of Filter in your adapter.i.e Do not create a new instance of filter in getFilter method.Use only a single instance of filter.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use only **one** single instance of `Filter` in your adapter to be able to cancel any previous non-executed filtering request. Don't create a new instance of `Filter` every time `getFilter` is called.

For example, initialize it on adapter initialization, and just return it from `getFilter` method.